# Install Clang 11 Error

Tags: clang

I’m trying to install clang-11 using command

Step 1

```
apt install clang-11
```

fails with error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> clang-11 :
> Depends: **libclang-cpp11** (>= 1:11.1.0~++20210428103820+1fdec59bffc1) but 1:11~++20200715091411+c86c1e972da-1~exp1~20200715072025.1806 is to be installed
> Depends: **libclang-common-11-dev** (= 1:11.1.0~++20210428103820+1fdec59bffc1-1~exp1~20210428204437.162) but 1:11~++20200715091411+c86c1e972da-1~exp1~20200715072025.1806 is to be installed
> Recommends: libomp-11-dev but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Step 2

```
apt install libclang-cpp11
```

fails with error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libclang-cpp11 : Depends: **libllvm11** (= 1:11.1.0~++20210428103820+1fdec59bffc1-1~exp1~20210428204437.162) but 1:11~++20200715091411+c86c1e972da-1~exp1~20200715072025.1806 is to be installed

Step 3
apt install libllvm11

fails with error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libllvm11 : Depends: **libtinfo6** (>= 6) but it is not installable

I have installed nurses but get libtinfo error. Can you let help in resolving dependency issue ?

Ubuntu Version: 18.04

Output of Command

```
 sudo apt-cache policy clang-11
```

> clang-11:
> Installed: (none)
> Candidate: 1:11.1.0~++20210428103820+1fdec59bffc1-1~exp1~20210428204437.162
> Version table:
> 1:11.1.0~++20210428103820+1fdec59bffc1-1~exp1~20210428204437.162 500
> 500 http://apt.llvm.org/buster llvm-toolchain-buster-11/main amd64 Packages

Comment: We don't know your OS & release for starters, and for best help you should provide full output as it looks like you're trying to hide details and without some of those details provided our ability is limited in what we can offer (we can't do command searches for packages until we know OS & release details)

Comment: Where you're getting `clang-11` from may also help, ie. `apt-cache policy clang-11`

Comment: I have attached the output . Source of package installation is pretty standard I found on net.

Comment: You are trying to use a Debian Buster/11 package on an old Ubuntu?  Are you surprised packages won't align correctly?  `clang-11` is available in Ubuntu repositories for later releases (`clang-10` is built for *bionic*).  If you need to use your release, I'd suggest looking for an appropriate source for `clang-11` for Ubuntu & not use one packaged for another OS & release, and please use {code} tags not text-quoting for command pastes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error is of using wrong source . With bionic problem got resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)